# Add custom company holidays to personal calendars without creating duplicate entries

Tags: vba, outlook, calendar

I completely changed the script.  However, when ran more than once it now creates duplicate calendar entries for all defined dates.  Not sure why its not locating duplicate subjects on each specific calendar day.

```
Const olFolderCalendar = 9
Const olAppointmentItem = 1
Const olOutOfOffice = 3
CRLF = Chr(13) & Chr(10)

' Initialize Outlook
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objCalendar = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

' Add holiday entries (modify as needed)
objDictionary.Add DateSerial(2023, 11, 23), "Thanksgiving Day"
objDictionary.Add DateSerial(2023, 11, 24), "Day After Thanksgiving Day"
objDictionary.Add DateSerial(2023, 12, 25), "Christmas Day"
objDictionary.Add DateSerial(2024, 1, 1), "New Years Day"
objDictionary.Add DateSerial(2024, 1, 15), "Martin Luther King Day"
objDictionary.Add DateSerial(2024, 5, 27), "Memorial Day"
objDictionary.Add DateSerial(2024, 7, 4), "Independence Day"
objDictionary.Add DateSerial(2024, 11, 28), "Thanksgiving Day"
objDictionary.Add DateSerial(2024, 11, 29), "Day After Thanksgiving Day"
objDictionary.Add DateSerial(2024, 12, 25), "Christmas Day"
objDictionary.Add DateSerial(2025, 1, 1), "New Years Day"

' Iterate through the dictionary
For Each dtmHolidayDate In objDictionary.Keys
    strHolidayName = objDictionary.Item(dtmHolidayDate)

    ' Check if an appointment with the same subject already exists
    Set objExistingHoliday = objCalendar.Items.Find("[Subject] = '" & strHolidayName & "' AND [Start] = '" & Month(dtmHolidayDate) & "/" & Day(dtmHolidayDate) & "/" & Year(dtmHolidayDate) & "'")
    If objExistingHoliday Is Nothing Then
        ' Create a new appointment item
        Set objHoliday = objOutlook.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
        With objHoliday
            .Subject = strHolidayName
            .Start = dtmHolidayDate
            .End = dtmHolidayDate
            .Categories = "Company Holidays"
            .AllDayEvent = True
            .ReminderSet = False
            .BusyStatus = olOutOfOffice
            .Save
        End With
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised it works at all - you are storing dates as strings, and you need to store then as dates, both in the dictionary, and when setting the `Start` and `End` properties. So the problem is that `objCalendar.Items.Find` does not find the appointment? Or that the check `objExistingHoliday.Start <> dtmHolidayDate` fails? In the latter case, you should be comparing the value of `objExistingHoliday.Start`, truncated to the date portion only with the date in your dictionary (which needs to be a Date, not string). Your really should not be comparing Date with a string (VBA will turn both of them into strings), and the dates must be suitably truncated (date only?) - `DateTime` is a float value and the `=` comparison will fail because of the truncation.

Comment: Well I modified the script using DateValue() in order format the dates in the dictionary, but it still is not working.  Not sure what else to do?

Comment: Please show your updated code (you can edit your post). `DateSerial` is a much better choice: `objDictionary.Add DateSerial(2023, 12, 25), "Christmas Day"``

Comment: Also make sure your comparison line is `If DateValue(objExistingHoliday.Start) <> DateValue(dtmHolidayDate) Then`